# How to fix the the direction of movement of a pinball and make it collide

Tags: python, game-physics, collision

I've made this pinball game program as an assignment for my class, and I've been stuck trying to fix the pinball movement and collision.

The first problem is that no matter which direction the user sets as the velocity, the ball only moves at a specific angle.

I don't really have any idea why it shouldn't be working, according to my notes, lecture slides, and discussion handouts, it should be fine. So does anyone have any idea why it isn't working? I've looked around and I couldn't find a definitive answer. Any help will be appreciated. I'm stumped :(

*Isn't working means that no matter which direction the user sets the pinball to go, it only goes in one direction (e.g. user sets pinball to go left, pinball goes right; user sets pinball to go up, it goes right; etc.)
Also, the pinball is not colliding with the walls or any of the targets.*

Graphics is graphics.py: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/index.html

here is the collision code (along with velocity reversal, only kept collision with right wall of game board):

```
def checkHit(ball,target,dispX,dispY,VelX,VelY,hit): ###pulled the definition out of the loop but keeping it here for easier reference
     center = ball.getCenter() ###defines the center of the pinball as a point
     hit = 0 ###used for differentiating between objects collided with
     if center.getX() + 1 <= 45 and center.getX() + 1 + dispX > 45: ####if the pinball collides with the right wall of the board
         VelX = VelX *(-1) ###velocity in the x direction reverses
         hit = 0  ###did not collide with a target

for j in range(1000):####1000 frames (ball isn't expected to last long in the air, only a couple seconds)
     vy = vy - 9.8 ###effect of gravity
     dx = vx / math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) ###speed in x direction over time
     dy = vy / math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) ###speed in y direction over time
     checkHit(pinball,target_front1,dx,dy,vx,vy,0) ####runs function each frame for collision testing
     pinball.move(dx , dy) ###moves pinball
```

Comment: Define "isn't working" in the context of your problem.

Comment: You mentioned "lecture notes".  Is this homework?  If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: Generally , try to avoid posting the entire code (especially when we can't access a necessary module, `graphics`) and refine it to a block of code as small as possible. Makes it easier for us to help you, and lets you understand the problem yourself.

Comment: Graphics.py is here http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure, because you haven't told us where you got the `graphics` module from. School  most likely.

Try changing some of the `if` statements to `elif`s. You're probably evaluating too many at the same time or something. Consider the following code, where you only want *ONE* of the following `if` statements to be run, but in reality, all of them are being run:

```
def foo(x):
 if x < 5:
  print 'x is greater than five'
 if x == 10:
  print 'x is 10'

foo(10)

>>> x is greater than 5
>>> x is 10
```

If you change the second `if` to an `elif`, then if the first `if` statement is run, the rest of the `elif`s are ignored:

```
def bar(x):
 if x < 5:
  print 'x is greater than five'
 elif x == 10:  #changed this line to an 'elif' 
  print 'x is 10'

bar(10)

>>> x is greater than 5   #only prints once, because the first if statement is True
```

You also define `checkHit` every loop, wasting system resources. Better to pull that out of the loop and into the top-most part of the module.

---

edit: Actually, the above example, while true, isn't very good. Imagine if `x`, a velocity, was more than `5`, a ball would stop rolling, so you'd change the `x` now to a `0`. Then you check it immediately after with a second `if` statement, to see if it's stopped. If it's stopped, start moving again (`x == 5` or something). This would mean that a ball would never stop moving, because no matter what, by the end of the `if` statement, the ball would always start moving again.

So what you'd need to do is use an `elif` statement instead of the second `if`, because the `elif` doesn't get evaluated unless the previous `if` statement is not `True`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried changing the multiple "if"s to some "elif"s but it didn't fix the problem =/

Comment: Go through the entire code, commenting every 3rd line at the very least and demonstrate that you understand what you are doing. It's going to be tedious, but you might figure out what you're doing wrong.  It doesn't seem like you've tried to remove parts of the code that aren't necessary to reproduce the bug. You've given us ~200 lines of code, when it probably only takes a quarter of that to reproduce the error.

Comment: Removed some redundant code, hoped that helps, sorry, I am new at this. I decided to just keep collision with the right wall as an example because the ball doesn't collide with anything.

Comment: It's all good man. The trick is to just post the code that will get us running. Usually that means some imports, like `graphics.py` and then the init stuff like `win = ...` then the logic that causes the issue.

Comment: All right, added those, and trimmed it down to the logic that I believe is messing it up.